# Ecodage Data factory DelimitedText source

Tags: azure, encoding, dataset, azure-data-factory

I have data factory pipeline with source (DelimitedText) on SFTP with ecodage ISO-8859-13, it was working without any problems with the special characetrs, but yesterday it's blocked with many errors, with the special characters,
Have you any solution for this problem ? whitch kind of encodage you use on ADF to read special characters (like this: commerçant)

Best regards,

I try to copy data with data factory pipeline

Answer (score 0):

ADF delimited text format supports below encoding types to read/write files.

[image]

Ref doc:  [ADF Delimited format dataset properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-delimited-text#dataset-properties)

I just tried with default encoding type `UTF-8` for the special character you have provided (like this: commerçant) and it works fine without any issue.

[image]

I have also tried with encoding type ISO-8859-13 and didn't notice any issue for the character type you have provided.

Hence assuming some other special characters might be causing the problem. But I would recommend trying to default `UTF-8` and see if that helps. In case if the issue still persists, then try using the Skip incompatible rows, which will help filter down the bad records and log them to a log file from where you can get the exact rows which are causing the pipeline to fail and based on those records you can choose the encoding type in your dataset settings.